# "How can I conditionally format the letters in a datatable?

Tags: r

I am new to R, I am currently trying to make a table that shows me what the variation is between 2 days and that once this variation is calculated if it is negative that the sea turns out with red letters if not then green

[image]

---

title: "**Area Comercial Consumo**"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns

### vertical_layout: fill

```
################## librerias #####################
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(DT)
library(htmlTable)
library(sqldf)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shinydashboard)

##################  Datos   #######################
base1     <- read_excel("C:/Karlo disco duro/AVANCE.xlsx",sheet = "Base1")
base2     <- read_excel("C:/Karlo disco duro/AVANCE.xlsx",sheet = "Base2")
finmes <- read_excel("C:/Karlo disco duro/AVANCE.xlsx",sheet = "Finmes")
```

### {width=20%}  {width=6%}

### **Avance de colocaciones diarias**

```
Green0 = "#DeF7E9"
Green = "#71CA97"
Red = "#ff7f7f"

data1<-subset(base1,select = c("TipoCredito","SaldoCapital"))
data2<-subset(base2,select = c("TipoCredito","SaldoCapital"))
finmes1<-subset(finmes,select = c("TipoCredito","SaldoCapital"))
final1<-data.frame(sqldf(
  "select TipoCredito, sum(SaldoCapital) as SALDO from data1 group by TipoCredito"
))
final2<-data.frame(sqldf(
  "select TipoCredito, sum(SaldoCapital) as SALDO from data2 group by TipoCredito"
))
finmes2<-data.frame(sqldf(
  "select TipoCredito, sum(SaldoCapital) as SALDO from finmes1 group by TipoCredito"
))

tablaa<-data.frame(final1)
tablab<-data.frame(final2)
tablafinmes<-data.frame(finmes2)

final3<-data.frame(sqldf(
  "select A.TipoCredito, A.SALDO as '23Agosto', B.SALDO as '24Agosto', (B.SALDO - A.SALDO) as VARIACION
  from tablaa A
  join tablab B on A.TipoCredito = B.TipoCredito
  group by A.TipoCredito"
))

finalfinmes <- data.frame(sqldf(
  "select F.TipoCredito, F.SALDO as '31Julio', B.SALDO as '24Agosto', (B.SALDO - F.SALDO) as VARIACION
  from tablafinmes F
  join tablab B on F.TipoCredito = B.TipoCredito
  group by F.TipoCredito"
))
```

```
my.options <- list (autoWidth = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   lengthChange = FALSE,
                   lengthMenu = FALSE,
                   pageLength = FALSE,
                   paging = FALSE,
                   info = FALSE)
##final<-formattable(final3,list(VARIACION = color_tile("red", "green")))

##final3.1<-formattable(final3, list(`VARIACION`=formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0, "red", "green")))))
##finalfinmes1<-formattable(finalfinmes, list(`VARIACION`=formatter("span", style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0, "red", "green")))))

Tablafinal<-datatable(final3,options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = 
                      list(list(width = '190px', targets = c(1,2,3,4))),pageLength = 7,searching = TRUE,
                   ordering = TRUE,
                   lengthChange = TRUE,
                   lengthMenu = FALSE,
                   pageLength = FALSE,
                   paging = FALSE,
                   info = FALSE), colnames = c('Tipo de credito','23 de Agosto','24 de Agosto', 'Variacion Diaria')) 

Tablafinalfinmes<-datatable(finalfinmes,options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = 
                      list(list(width = '190px', targets = c(1,2,3,4))),pageLength = 7,searching = TRUE,
                   ordering = TRUE,
                   lengthChange = TRUE,
                   lengthMenu = FALSE,
                   pageLength = FALSE,
                   paging = FALSE,
                   info = FALSE),colnames = c('Tipo de credito','31 de Julio','24 de Agosto', 'Variacion fin de mes'))
##%>% formatStyle('VARIACION',color = ifelse('VARIACION'>0,'Green','Red')))

##Tablafinal$VARIACION <- ifelse(Tablafinal$VARIACION < 0, 1, ifelse(Tablafinal$VARIACION > 0, 2,3))

Tablafinal1<- formatStyle(Tablafinal,
                        columns = c(4),
                        fontFamily = "Arial",
                        fontSize = "16px", 
                        color = ifelse('VARIACION'< -0,'#ed1c16','#0ca649'))
                       ## backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1, 2,3), c('green', 'yellow','red')))
                        ##color = styleEqual(c(-1,0,1),c('green','blue','Yellow')))

Tablafinalfinmes1<- formatStyle(Tablafinalfinmes,
                        columns = c(4),
                        fontFamily = "Arial",
                        fontSize = "16px",
                        color = ifelse('VARIACION'< -0,'#ed1c16','#0ca649'))

Tablafinal1$VARIACION <- ifelse(Tablafinal1$VARIACION < 0, 1, 
                    ifelse(Tablafinal1$VARIACION > 0, 2))

ab <- Tablafinal1 %>% formatCurrency (c('X23Agosto','X24Agosto','VARIACION'), 's/ ') %>% formatStyle('TipoCredito',target = 'row',backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('CONSUMO NO REVOLVENTE','CONSUMO REVOLVENTE','HIPOTECARIO'),c('#f8fb63','#f8fb63','#f8fb63'))) %>% formatStyle('VARIACION',fontWeight = 'bold',fontSize = "13px") 

##ab1 <- ab %>% formatStyle(columns = c('VARIACION'),valueColumns = c('VARIACION'),target='row',Color = styleEqual(c(-1,1),
##                                                                      c('red','green')))

tf <- Tablafinalfinmes1 %>% formatCurrency (c('X31Julio','X24Agosto','VARIACION'),'s/ ')%>% formatStyle('TipoCredito',target = 'row',backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('CONSUMO NO REVOLVENTE','CONSUMO REVOLVENTE','HIPOTECARIO'),c('#f8fb63','#f8fb63','#f8fb63'))) %>% formatStyle('VARIACION',fontWeight = 'bold',fontSize = "13px")

##ui<- fluidPage (navlistPanel(tabPanel("Variacion Diaria",ab),
##                  tabPanel("Variacion Mensual")))
##ui<-formattable(ab, list(VARIACION = color_tile("red", "green")))
ui<- fluidPage (tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Variacion Diaria",ab),
              tabPanel("Variacion Mensual",tf)))
```

## INICIO

### row{.tabset} {width=80}

```
ui
```

Comment: i have the code, i'm new here

Comment: I already uploaded the sample code, I hope it is understandable

Comment: This should help you: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Comment: I already did this but only the entire "variation" column colored me green and it is not conditioned if it is negative, it is as if it did not detect the negative value

Comment: Is `backgroundColor` not working as in [the vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `color = ifelse('VARIACION'< -0,'#ed1c16','#0ca649')` is evaluating whether the string VARIACION is less than 0. While that is not a particularly meaningful question, R does indeed evaluates that to FALSE (in all your cases) and thus prints things in green as a result.

More generally, you do not want to use `ifelse()` in this case. Use something like `formatStyle('VARIACION',  color = styleInterval(0, c("red", "green"))` instead.

The key here is `styleInterval()` which defines cut points and colors for intervals. When you put one cut point (e.g. at 0) and two colors, it uses the first color before the cut point and the second after. You can have multiple intervals though (cut points > 1). You just need one more color than you have cut points (e.g., try something like `color = styleInterval(c(0,300000), c("red", "green","blue")))` in my example below).

Below is a working example modified from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html:

```
library(DT)
m = cbind(matrix(rnorm(60, 1e5, 1e6), 20), runif(20), rnorm(20, 100))
m[, 1:3] = round(m[, 1:3])
m[, 4:5] = round(m[, 4:5], 7)
colnames(m) = head(LETTERS, ncol(m))
head(m)

datatable(m) %>% 
  formatCurrency(c('A', 'C')) %>% 
  formatStyle('A',  color = styleInterval(0, c("red", "green")))
```

Note further that a more proper implementation using `ifelse()` still fails since it returns a vector and the color option doesn't want a vector (as a result it does not throw an error but also doesn't plot). So again, don't use `ifelse()` here.

```
#this fails
datatable(m) %>% 
  formatCurrency(c('A', 'C')) %>% 
  formatStyle('A',  color = ifelse(m[,"A"] < 0, "red", "green"))
```

Comment: could you explain to me how a little more detail works please: color = styleInterval(0, c("red", "green")) and color = ifelse(m[,"A"] < 0, "red", "green"), 
I thank you in advance

Comment: For clarification on stuff like this is is often best to use the R help files. Typing ?styleInterval() will bring up the help page.